# Which swing containers can be set focusable?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jpanel

I’m using a `JPanel` to add `JComponents` on and I tried to set the `JPanel` focusable so when the user clicks on the `JPanel`, it will unselect any `JComponent` and call that `JComponent`’s listener. I've read pretty much every Q&A asked about this and I can't find anything that works. So then I thought: is there another container that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `panel.requestFocus();`? Since `JPanel` is a sub class of `Component` it could also call this method. This will take focus from whatever has it at the particular moment.

**EDIT:**

Here goes a code sample showing it working.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PanelOnClickGrabFocus {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                final JPanel p = new JPanel();
                p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
                JTextField tf = new JTextField(34);
                p.add(tf);
                f.setContentPane(p);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
                p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {    
                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        p.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the **EDIT** where you will find a code sample presenting what I said.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use any container that implements the `FocusListener` interface. Create your own or use on the know implemented interfaced described in the documentation.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusListener.html