# Prevent table cell losing focus when underlying row model is updated

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have an editable `JTable`. If a user is editing a cell when the underlying row model is updated the cell editor loses focus.

What's the simplest solution to this?

Comment: this question invoke me ... please to add `startEditAt()` to the 56th. line in your `CustomCellEditor`, maybe fixing that, now without jokes, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: and with to override PropertyChangeEvent, JtableCellEditor fired these events on every change of ...

Comment: please bunch of questions in your comment are `1)` for me `2)` for down_voter

Comment: now about nothing, my comments here are about TableCellEditor, not about FocusOwner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution to this, as @mKorbel noticed, very theoretical question :) is to:

1. Always remember which cell has the focus.
2. Listen to row changes.
3. When the underlying row is changed at the end of the method, called after the change is done, give back the focus to the right cell, e.g. using `requestFocus()`, [example available here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11033512/613495)